# Pass data among users through a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, server

New to chrome extensions. I want to develop an extension where users can drag and drop text or urls to their extension and it automatically syncs up and displays on another user's extension. Should I be using a server to push/pull data to?

Comment: See also [How to Send text messages browser to browser in webrtc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14133037)

Answer (score 0):

Basically: yes. Provided APIs do not give you the power to interact between users.

Chrome provides a concept of sync storage, but it's only to syncing small amounts of data between browser sessions *of the same user*.

You may want to use `chrome.identity` to avoid the hassle of making a separate login for your users.